# server_tokens off but still publishing them

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I added

```
server_tokens off;
```

to http{} section of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and restarted nginx with

```
service nginx restart
```

command. but server still publishing the server tokens when responsing to request. I also checked under the sites-enabled/available config files for if is there any server_tokens on, but no there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:)

I finally found the reason. "X-Powered-By" header was added by PHP. so I edited the php.ini to

```
expose_php = off;
```

and it's gone. Just "Server: nginx" left and it's not important for me :)